# notify user from service with python

Tags: python-3.x, service, tty, inetd

In the following text the word "write" refers to the unix write command which writes a message to another user's tty.

I have a service running (in inetd, but that shouldn't matter) which needs to notify an arbitrary user. Until now I tried to call the write command with subprocess. But that doesn't work always and on some machines leads to an error message like:

```
write: you are uid 65534, but your login is as uid 1000
```

(please note that the service is running as nobody.) Write permission to the terminal is turned on with mesg. So I looked at inetutils-talkd (the GNU implementation), which does the same. I saw that it uses the ttymsg function and believe that this function does what I want, but I think that this function isn't available to python.

So the main questions are: Is there something like the ttymsg function in python OR how can i get write to do what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file /var/run/utmp contains information about the active sessions on terminals.
It can be parsed with:

```
import struct

sig = 'hi32s4s32s256shhiii36x'
size = struct.calcsize(sig)
file = open('/var/run/utmp', 'rb')
chunk = file.read(size)
entrys = []
while len(chunk) == size:
    entry = struct.unpack(chunk)
    entrys.append()
    chunk = file.read(size)
```

With that approach I can gather the needed data to choose a terminal and write to that terminal.